# How to hide and unhide Windows 11 taskbar Quick Launch while keeping the positions of the shortcuts?

Tags: windows, windows-11, taskbar, quicklaunch

I wanted to hide the QuickLaunch area in Windows 11 taskbar because I didn't want to show it in a meeting where I am sharing my desktop. So I right-click in an empty area in the taskbar, select Toolbars, and uncheck 'Quick Launch'. When I wanted to unhide it, I tried to reverse the action and check it. 'Quick Launch' was gone, so I had to recreate it.
To my disappointment, all the shortcuts, the icons, were in different positions. Not in the places where I expect them to be. I have over 30 shortcuts.

Is there a way I can hide/unhide the Quick Launch area in the taskbar easily and maintain the current icons positions?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply Unpin Quick Access from the taskbar.

Right click on the QA icon in the taskbar. Select Unpin.

Here is a good Microsoft Article:

[QU Information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/customize-the-quick-access-toolbar-43fff1c9-ebc4-4963-bdbd-c2b6b0739e52#:%7E:text=Quick%20Access%20Toolbar-,Show%20or%20hide%20the%20Quick%20Access%20Toolbar,select%20Show%20Quick%20Access%20Toolbar.)

It will no longer be in the task bar but will remain in Windows Explorer. Explorer shortcuts remain.

This is how it works for native Windows 11.  I have tested this.

QA is not a toolbar, so you may have a 3rd party Start App that causes the QA behavior you have.

If you are using 3rd party stuff to you will most likely have to live with closing QA when you need to and live with the consequences of re-arranged icons.

Comment: I don't have a QA icon. The QA is a place with shortcuts as icons. Clicking anywhere in there does not show me an unpin option. 
I am using a third party start app.

I don't know about QA is not a toolbar. To create a QA, I select new toolbar under Toobars. To me then it's a toolbar.

Comment: Your 3rd party stuff (not native Windows) is why you have issues.   My answer is correct for proper Windows 11.

Comment: I don't know what is the QA icon you're referring to. I have never seen one, with or without start apps. 
As for the new positions I saw, it seems it's alphabetically sorted by shortcut filenames. That makes sense.

Comment: It will show up as an Explorer Icon.  I posted a Microsoft Link in my answer to assist you.

Comment: That's Quick Access toolbar in an Office app. I am talking about Quick Launch in Windows taskbar.

Comment: QA in the taskbar is the Windows Explorer icon.

Comment: I am trying to help you but my system is different than yours. I can right click the Explorer icon, remove it from taskbar, and re-add it with no change in Explorer organization.